# Weaving production classes with AspectJ aspects in Maven for tests execution only

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, aspectj

I have a project with Maven build and need to add some basic performance tracing to methods. I decided to use AspectJ for this. Main requirement is to weave tracing aspect into production classes **but only for unit tests execution phase**.

I was able to configure weaving in Maven however after execution of tests same production classes with aspect applied go to packaged war.

The case looks like pretty common nevertheless I wasn't able to find solution for it in web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that in a dedicated module, use the Maven Dependency Plugin to unpack the artifact "under test" during the `generate-test-sources` phase, then weave the classes and finally run the tests.

---

Let me try to illustrate what I mean. Let's imagine the following project structure:

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- some-module    // this is the module that we want to weave 
    |-- pom.xml    // but only for testing purpose
    `-- ...
```

So my suggestion is to do something like this:

```
.
|-- pom.xml
|-- some-module      
|   |-- pom.xml      
|   `-- ...
`-- test-module    // we're going to weave the classes here because we don't want
    |-- pom.xml    // the tracing aspect to be packaged in the "production" jar
    `-- ...
```

The idea is to have an additional "test-module" where we would unpack the artifact that we want to test so that we can weave its classes without affecting the "real" production jar.

To do so, declare a dependency on the module under test and use `dependency:unpack` to unpack the classes into `target/classes` before invoking the AspectJ plugin to weave the "main" classes.

Comment: Pascal, thank you for answer. However I'm not sure I got your point. Let me try to clarify.

Comment: You proposing to put production code into separate Maven module and don't put tests there at all. Then main project will contain tests only. At the process-test-classes (I assume this is the phase you meant) it will unpack production classes from separate module to test classes folder and weave aspects into them. Then it will run tests. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Pascal, I think now I understand. I will try suggested approach and let you know results.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your aspects in the test directory and set the weaveMainSourceFolder flag to true in the test-compile configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>test-compile</id>
                <configuration>
                    <weaveMainSourceFolder>true</weaveMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/test-compile-mojo.html

Comment: So, does this result in your packaged jar not having the woven version?  This worked for me in the sense that my tests now work, but on the face of it, it seems like the JAR file that I'm packaging for my main source files will now be the woven versions.  Or, does it make a separate copy for test or something?  Do I need to skip tests when making the final version of my package?

Comment: To answer the question in my prior comment: yes, this method results in the main sources being woven in your production release.  I solved this by changing to load-time weaving, which is probably the best way to use the weaving during test runs only.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with load-time weaving.  That way the weaving happens when your unit-tests are run (via a command line argument when running unit-tests), but your aspects are not woven into the published artifacts.

For example, I wanted to fake out the system clock in my unit-tests, but obviously not mess with it in the live code.  Here's my aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class TweakSystemAspects {
    private static long timeOffsetMillis = 0;

    public static void advanceTime(int amount, TimeUnit unit) {
        timeOffsetMillis += unit.toMillis(amount);
    }

    @Around("call (long System.currentTimeMillis())")
    public long aroundSystemTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return ((Long) joinPoint.proceed()) + timeOffsetMillis;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is used in unit-tests by calling the `TweakSystemAspects.advanceTime()` mehtod to fake the passage of time in the system.  To accomplish the load time weaving, I just had to make an aop.xml file that defined my aspects (and that weaving should happen in all classes):

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.mypackage.TweakSystemAspects"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-nowarn -Xlint:ignore"/>
    <!-- During testing this was useful, but I didn't want all that output normally. -->
    <!--<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo"/>-->
</aspectj>
```

Finally, I made changes in my pom file to declare the AspectJ runtime dependency and tell surefire to do run-time weaving.

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        ...
        <version.aspectj>1.8.10</version.aspectj>
    <properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- For Load Time Weaving of our AspectJ helper code -->
                    <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${version.aspectj}/aspectjweaver-${version.aspectj}.jar</argLine>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the sample provided in [AspectJ compiler Maven Plugin - Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html) something like the following should work:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           ...
       </plugins>
   <build>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: This will weave test classes, which is not what the OP wants. The OP wants to weave "main" classes, but only for the purpose of testing (the tracing aspect shouldn't be included in the packaged classes).

Comment: Pascal, you're exactly right. Problem with AspectJ maven plugin is that it weaves production aspects to production classes and test aspects to test classes but I need to "mix" them.

Comment: Down-voting because this doesn't at all address the OP issue.